# Call generic closure with concrete type

Tags: generics, rust, traits, generic-function

Is it possible to call a generic function using a concrete type, with a concrete struct?

Here a small example of what I want to do:

```
trait T {}
trait T2 {}
struct S1 {}
struct S2 {}
impl T for S1 {}
impl T for S2 {}

fn test<V: T>(foo: &S1, bar: &S2, f: &Fn(&V)) {
    f::<S1>(foo);
    f(bar);
}

fn main() {
    test(&S1{}, &S2{}, &|_| println!("called"));
}
```

I can't get rid of the generic parameter `V` because the actual problem  I want to solve is much more involved. Furthermore I can't create a wrapping trait, because sometimes I have got a weak signature and sometimes `f` requires many more traits.

Comment: Note that every time `test` is called, it is expected that `V` can be instantiated to _one_ type. You would like to move the universal quantification of `V` to `Fn`. Unfortunately, that isn't directly possible. Maybe [this will help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606035/pass-generic-function-as-argument)

Comment: This wouldn't solve my problem since I want to pass in several diffrent functions. A Trait can't help either, because the generics would have to be speciefied on a method. Therefore I can't make it into an Object...
Is there no way to avoid the monomorphization in this context ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible:

```
fn test<V: T>(foo: &S1, bar: &S2, f: &Fn(&V)) {
    f::<S1>(foo);
}
```

In effect, the function signature says:

- Please give me an `f` that takes a trait object of the trait `Fn` which takes a reference to a `V`
- The *caller* is allowed to pick any concrete type for `V`, so long as it implements the trait `T`

Then the body of the function says:

- HAHAHA, just kidding, I'm going to call that `f` with the concrete type `S1`, regardless of what the caller picked.

This cannot work because the `V` that the caller picked *might not be `S1`*. In fact, it's most likely **not** going to be `S1`.

About the only suggestion I can offer is to accept another trait object as the argument:

```
fn test(foo: &S1, bar: &S2, f: &Fn(&T)) {
    f(foo);
    f(bar);
}
```

but you've already ruled that out, so...

---

As a side note, I'm not sure why you are taking the closure as a trait object. Normally, I'd just accept a generic:

```
fn test<F>(foo: &S1, bar: &S2, f: F)
    where F: Fn(&T),
```

This allows for some level of monomorphization to occur.

Comment: Thought so too, just wanted to be sure.
It needed to be a trait object since I need this closure to be `Sized`

Comment: @Cooki3Tube `f` would be `Sized` in the last code block I show (otherwise it couldn't be a parameter!); so I must be misunderstanding you.

Comment: I tried this an hour ago and the compiler complained... Now I tried this again and the compiler doesn't complain about this anymore. Strange

Comment: Do you have any advice how I could do this?
I just need some logic to be given as a colsure which can operate on S1 and S2

Comment: @Cooki3Tube you'd have to expand on your question a bit more. The code in both answers shows calling the closure with both `S1` and `S2`.

Comment: Okay the less simplified version is: I want to be able to do something like the following [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ef8cbfa01aae4cbd82b0ecab39b4c96e&version=stable&backtrace=0) I explain my problem there in a bit more detail

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you want, but it works:

```
trait T {}
trait T2 {}
struct S1 {}
struct S2 {}
impl T for S1 {}
impl T for S2 {}

fn test<F>(foo: &S1, bar: &S2, f: F) 
where F: Fn (&T)
{
   f(foo as &T);
   f(bar as &T);
}

fn main() {
   test(&S1{}, &S2{}, |_| println!("called"));
}
```

This causes foo and bar to be cast to a Trait object, which means that it will carry a vtable pointer (may not be desirable). It makes the F a polymorphic call.

Without more information about your types, it's hard to understand what you're trying to do.