# Why is "one type is more general than the other" in an Option containing a closure?

Tags: rust

I wrote some code that compiled fine, then I turned `T` into `Option<T>` and now I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched type...one type is more general than the other
```

When building a minimal case I noticed that if I change `data: &str` into `data: String` the code compiles fine again.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bbdc3a49b37d07d1a07407766266936a)

```
pub trait Subscriber {
    fn recv(&mut self, data: &str);
}

pub struct Task<T>(pub Option<T>)
where
    T: Fn(&str);

impl<T> Subscriber for Task<T>
where
    T: Fn(&str),
{
    fn recv(&mut self, data: &str) {
        self.0.take().unwrap()(data)
    }
}

fn main() {
    Task(Some(|_| ()));
}
```

Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: Does this help you https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=afdfa3ac283b859de2b08ba76d895cff ?

Comment: I've noted that using closures without argument types in a generic context does not work properly. I don't know if it is a compiler bug, a type system limitation, or a lack of understanding of mine. But changing the last line to: `Task(Some(|_: &str| ()));` makes it work.

Comment: It's especially confusing that "expected type" and "found type" are shown with the exact same representation in the error message. Even if the behavior is otherwise correct, that looks like a bug in the compiler diagnostics.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You seem to have hit a quirk in the compiler. The toilet closure (`|_|()`) generalizes into a function which is generic over its input type (`<T> Fn(T)`),
but in such a way that does not fulfill the intended constraint over the lifetime of `T`. What we need here is a function that is generic over the lifetime of the input due to the bound `for<'a> Fn(&'a str)` in the implementation of `Subscriber` for `Task<T>`.

(Due to the current lifetime elision rules, the higher-ranked trait bound in `Subscriber` can be written without explicitly indicating `for<'a>`. This expansion was made in the previous paragraph for clarity.)

This is made a bit clearer by the compiler if you try to actually use the `Task` value as a `Subscriber`:

```rust
let mut task = Task(Some(|_| ()));
task.recv("Message");
```

The error message:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `recv` found for struct `Task<[closure@src/main.rs:19:30: 19:36]>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:20:10
   |
5  | / pub struct Task<T>(pub Option<T>)
6  | | where
7  | |     T: Fn(&str);
   | |                -
   | |                |
   | |________________method `recv` not found for this
   |                  doesn't satisfy `_: Subscriber`
...
19 |       let mut task = Task(Some(|_| ()));
   |                                ------
   |                                |
   |                                doesn't satisfy `<_ as std::ops::FnOnce<(&str,)>>::Output = ()`
   |                                doesn't satisfy `_: std::ops::Fn<(&str,)>`
20 |       task.recv("Message");
   |            ^^^^ method not found in `Task<[closure@src/main.rs:19:30: 19:36]>`
   |
   = note: the method `recv` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<[closure@src/main.rs:19:30: 19:36] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&str,)>>::Output = ()`
           which is required by `Task<[closure@src/main.rs:19:30: 19:36]>: Subscriber`
           `[closure@src/main.rs:19:30: 19:36]: std::ops::Fn<(&str,)>`
           which is required by `Task<[closure@src/main.rs:19:30: 19:36]>: Subscriber`
```

By explicitly marking the closure's single input parameter as a reference, the closure will then no longer generalize over the parameter type `T`, but over a higher-ranked lifetime of the reference input `'a` in `&'a _`.

```
let mut task = Task(Some(|_: &_| ()));
task.recv("Message");
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2aca7e2c25c5a56b319c3189aa166565).

While not impossible, adjusting the compiler to successfully infer the right type for the original closure would possibly require substantial changes to the current monomorphization rules.

See also:

- [Why isn't `std::mem::drop` exactly the same as the closure |_|() in higher-ranked trait bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59023616)