# Rust: Why does the binding of the closure to a variable change the type?

Tags: rust, closures

I have this (most simplified) piece of code:

```rust
fn returns_closure() -> Box<dyn Fn(&u64)> {
    let closure = |_| ();
    Box::new(closure)
}
```

This does not compile with a rather unhelpful error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     Box::new(closure)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
  |
  = note: expected type `FnOnce<(&u64,)>`
             found type `FnOnce<(&u64,)>`
```

However, when I don't bind the closure to a variable first, and create it directly in the constructor of the Box, it does compile:

```rust
fn returns_closure() -> Box<dyn Fn(&u64)> {
    Box::new(|_| ())
}
```

Why does the first one fail to compile, and what is the difference between the two?

---

Edit:
Emouns answer seems to be correct.
I compiled the exact same code with the nightly toolchain (1.52.0), and got a better error:

```
error: implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     Box::new(closure)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
  |
  = note: closure with signature `fn(&'2 u64)` must implement `FnOnce<(&'1 u64,)>`, for any lifetime `'1`...
  = note: ...but it actually implements `FnOnce<(&'2 u64,)>`, for some specific lifetime `'2`
```

Comment: black magic probably (yes I have no idea)

Comment: My guess: it looks like the compiler can't infer the closure type in the first implementation.. (or as mentioned above, magic)

Comment: I think this might be related to the fact, that the closure generalizes into a function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63917951/4593433

Comment: You can use `let closure = |_: &u64| ();` instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @frankenapps pointed out, if you use `let closure = |_: &u64|();` then you don't get this error. So what is going on?

To try to figure this out I made the following edits that use explicit lifetimes (instead of having the compiler elide them for us) in an effort to get the same error message:

```rust
fn returns_closure<'a>() -> Box<dyn Fn(&'_ u64)> {
    let closure = |_: &'a u64| ();
    Box::new(closure)
}
```

Running this code gives us the following error message:

```
rror[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     Box::new(closure)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
  |
  = note: expected type `for<'r> Fn<(&'r u64,)>`
             found type `Fn<(&'a u64,)>`
note: this closure does not fulfill the lifetime requirements
 --> src/lib.rs:3:19
  |
3 |     let closure = |_: &'a u64| ();
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     Box::new(closure)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
  |
  = note: expected type `FnOnce<(&u64,)>`
             found type `FnOnce<(&'a u64,)>`
note: this closure does not fulfill the lifetime requirements
 --> src/lib.rs:3:19
  |
3 |     let closure = |_: &'a u64| ();
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The error message is not the exact same, since we are using explicit lifetimes, but the type of error is still `one type is more general than the other`.

So what we see here might be an error in lifetime elision.
You can see that I have given the closure the same lifetime as the function (`'a`), however the function returns `dyn Fn(&'_ u64)`. Here notice the `'_` which is a stand-in for any lifetime, not just `'a`.
Therefore, the return type `&'_ u64`is more general (accepts more lifetimes) than the closure (`&'a u64`) and we get the error.

I tried other lifetime combinations, but this one was the only one to give this type of error. But whether this is actually what is going on I cannot say.