# How do I pass reference parameters to boxed closures?

Tags: rust, callback, closures

I want to store a callback that can take different types of parameters (both owned values and references), and can also modify its environment (hence the FnMut). When invoking the callback with a reference, I'd like the compiler to enforce that the parameter is only valid in the closure body. I've tried to implement this using boxed closures.

A minimum example shown below:

```
fn main() {
    let mut caller = Caller::new();
    let callback = |x: &Foo| println!("{:?}", x);
    caller.register(callback);
    
    let foo = Foo{
        bar: 1,
        baz: 2,
    };
    
    //callback(&foo);       // works
    caller.invoke(&foo);    // borrowed value does not live long enough

}

struct Caller<'a, T> {
    callback: Box<dyn FnMut(T) + 'a>
}

impl<'a, T> Caller<'a, T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Caller {
            callback: Box::new(|_| ()),
        }
    }
    
    fn register(&mut self, cb: impl FnMut(T) + 'a) {
        self.callback = Box::new(cb);
    }
    
    fn invoke(&mut self, x: T) {
        (self.callback)(x);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Foo {
    bar: i32,
    baz: i32,
}
```

I want to understand why this works if I directly call `callback()` but the compiler complains about lifetimes if I invoke it through a struct than owns the closure. Perhaps it has something to do with the `Box`? I can get this to work if I define `foo` before `caller`, but I'd like to avoid this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is yet another example of the compiler's type inference quirks when working with closures and bounds of a similar sort ([issue #41078](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41078)). Although this `Caller<'a, T>` may seem to be well capable of handling `invoke` calls for a given generic `T`, the given example passes a reference `&'b Foo` (where `'b` would be some anonymous lifetime of that value). And due to this limitation, `T` was inferred to be a `&Foo` of one expected lifetime, which is different from a reference of any lifetime to a value of type `Foo` (`for<'a> &'a Foo`), and incompatible with the reference passed to the `invoke` call.

By not passing the closure to `Caller`, the compiler would be able to correctly infer the expected parameter type of the callback, including reference lifetime.

One way to overcome this is to redefine `Caller` to explicitly receive a reference value as the callback parameter. This changes the behavior of the inferred type `&T` into a higher-ranked lifetime bound, as hinted above.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb5eb097813b99060ed624c3b9bd01df)

```
fn main() {
    let mut caller = Caller::new();
    let callback = |x: &Foo| { println!("{:?}", x) };
    caller.register(callback);

    let foo = Foo { bar: 1, baz: 2 };

    caller.invoke(&foo);
}

struct Caller<'a, T> {
    callback: Box<dyn FnMut(&T) + 'a>,
}

impl<'a, T> Caller<'a, T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Caller {
            callback: Box::new(|_| ()),
        }
    }

    fn register(&mut self, cb: impl FnMut(&T) + 'a) {
        self.callback = Box::new(cb);
    }

    fn invoke(&mut self, x: &T) {
        (self.callback)(x);
    }
}
```

One way to make this clearer would be to use the expanded definition of `invoke`:

```
    fn register<F>(&mut self, cb: F)
    where 
        F: for<'b> FnMut(&'b T) + 'a
    {
        self.callback = Box::new(cb);
    }
```

See also:

- [Why is "one type is more general than the other" in an Option containing a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63916821)
- [Type mismatches resolving a closure that takes arguments by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36415348)
- [How to declare a lifetime for a closure argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31403723)

Comment: Is this a use case for HRTB where we really want to express the `F` bound as `F: for<'b, T: 'b> FnMut(T) + 'a`?

Comment: @user4815162342 I suppose that could help, so long as this trait bound would also flow into the receiver type.

Comment: Is there a way to still allow the callback to receive an owned value as the parameter?