# Static future doesn't live long enough

Tags: rust, async-await, lifetime

Playing around with async/await I stumbled across this lifetime puzzle. I assume that `predicate` takes a reference/value and produces static future - it has no reference to its arguments and captures no values. Instead I got complain about lifetime being too short.

Why it fails and where's the lifetime `'2`?

```rust
use futures::future;
use std::future::Future;

fn validate<F, Fut>(_: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&str) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = bool>,
{
}

fn predicate(_: impl AsRef<str>) -> impl Future<Output = bool> {
    future::ready(true)
}

fn main() {
    validate(|x| predicate(x));
}
```

Error message:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:16:18
   |
16 |     validate(|x| predicate(x));
   |               -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |               ||
   |               |return type of closure is impl futures::Future
   |               has type `&'1 str`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: I think it is related to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59101369/865874).  You can fix it by adding another generic to your `validate`: `where R: AsRef<str>, F: FnMut(R) -> Fut,`...

Comment: The abyss gaped upon me. I definitely need some time to process it. Thanks for pointing out to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message here is a little confusing because it's talking about two lifetimes, `'1` and `'2`, but doesn't actually say what `'2` refers to.

There are two lifetimes that matter here:

- the `&str` argument, which the message labels with lifetime `'1`
- the future type variable `Fut`, which is labeled  with lifetime `'2` in the message, though it doesn't clearly state that.

The inferred lifetimes (using the [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html)) for `predicate` are like this:

```
fn predicate<'x>(_: impl AsRef<str> + 'x) -> impl Future<Output = bool> + 'x {
    future::ready(true)
}
```

Even though the implementation doesn't actually use the string input, it would be weird if it didn't, so this is probably correct for a *real* implementation. The compiler has inferred  that the return value of a function uses the input, so they must have compatible lifetimes.

However, the lifetimes for `validate` are inferred to be different:

```
fn validate<'1, '2, F, Fut>(_: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&'1 str) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = bool> + '2,
{
}
```

This function accepts arguments with broader requirements than `predicate`, which means it can't guarantee to enforce the constraints that `predicate` needs.

You can fix that by making it explicit in the type of `validate`:

```
fn validate<'a, F, Fut>(_: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&'a str) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = bool> + 'a,
{
}
```

Constraining both types with the `'a` lifetime communicates that `validate` expects `F` to use data from the `&str`, and therefore will ensure that the string lives long enough. Any implementation of `validate` that broke this contract would also not compile.

Comment: I wounder why it still fails if I change `predicate` return type to `impl Future<Output = bool> + 'static`. I thought `'static` should fit any lifetime restriction then.

Comment: At the same time if I replace return type with direct `future::Ready<bool>` it works perfectly well. I expected it to be equivalent to `impl Future<Output = bool> + 'static`