# Why can't Rust coerce an async function with a lifetime parameter to a function pointer?

Tags: generics, rust, async-await, lifetime

I'd like to write a function which takes one argument: a pointer to an async function taking a lifetime parameter.

Here's a minimal example:

```rust
use std::future::Future;

async fn takes_i32_ref<'a>(r: &'a i32) { }

fn takes_fn<F: Future>(f: for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> F) { }

fn main() {
    takes_fn(takes_i32_ref);
}
```

When I try to run this I get the message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:8:14
  |
8 |     takes_fn(takes_i32_ref);
  |     -------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
  |     |
  |     arguments to this function are incorrect
  |
  = note: expected fn pointer `for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> _`
                found fn item `for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> impl for<'a> Future<Output = ()> {takes_i32_ref}`
note: function defined here
 --> src/main.rs:5:4
  |
5 | fn takes_fn<F: Future>(f: for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> F) { }
  |    ^^^^^^^^            ---------------------------
```

I found a question that seemed pretty related: [Why isn't `std::mem::drop` exactly the same as the closure |_|() in higher-ranked trait bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59023616/why-isnt-stdmemdrop-exactly-the-same-as-the-closure-in-higher-ranke)

I think that question is different from mine though. In that question, a `for<'a> FnOnce<(&'a &str,)>` is expected and a `FnOnce<(&&str,)>` is provided. The provided type is **less** general than the expected type because it lacks a `for`.

However, my example says that a `for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> _` is expected and a `for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> impl for<'a> Future<Output = ()> {takes_i32_ref}` is provided. The provided type is **more** general than the expected type because it has a `for`.

Why can't Rust do this coercion?

Edit: I should also add that this error doesn't appear when I get rid of the reference in the signature of `takes_i32_ref` and `f`. That the async function takes a parameter with a lifetime seems to be important.

Comment: Is the goal here to define a function that takes a function argument that returns a Future?

Comment: I'm trying to define a function that takes an async function that takes a parameter with a lifetime. My understanding is that yes, that means I'm trying to define a function that takes a function argument that returns a future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The future returned by an `async` function is only valid for as long as the arguments are. Therefore, the return type may depend on the argument lifetimes. So, per the [original RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2394-async_await.md), the type of `takes_i32_ref` is really something like

```
fn takes_i32_ref<'a>(r: &'a i32) -> impl Future<Output = ()> + 'a
```

Now it should be clear why your code doesn't work: `takes_fn`'s `F` cannot depend on `'a`; you've written that `takes_fn` takes a function that, `for` all `'a`, returns the same type `F`. `takes_i32_ref` is not such a function, so `takes_fn(takes_i32_ref)` fails.

In an alternate universe/future Rust, this might be fixable with higher-kinded polymorphism:

```
// imaginary syntax
fn takes_fn<F<'a>: Future + 'a>(f: for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> F<'a>) { }
// which would be the same as (also imaginary, but at least this one parses...)
fn takes_fn(f: for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> (impl Future + 'a)) { }
```

In current nightly Rust, you can create a trait containing an `async fn` and then implement that. (This is possible since traits now support generic associated types, which is very close to higher kinded polymorphism.).

```
#![feature(async_fn_in_trait)]

trait TakesI32Ref { // equivalent to the imaginary trait for<'a> Fn(&'a i32) -> (impl Future + 'a), not really a function pointer as you wrote
    async fn call<'a>(&self, r: &'a i32) -> ();
}
enum Impl { ImplVal }
impl TakesI32Ref for Impl {
    async fn call<'a>(&self, _r: &'a i32) { }
}
fn takes_fn<F: TakesI32Ref>(f: F) {
    let x: i32 = 5;
    f.call(&x);
}
fn main() {
    takes_fn(Impl::ImplVal);
}
```

To force it to work in stable, for a nonzero performance penalty, you can use `dyn`.

```
fn takes_fn<O>(f: for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> Box<dyn Future<Output = O> + 'a>) { }

fn main() {
    takes_fn(|r| Box::new(takes_i32_ref(r)));
}
```